# Colocar una cita bibliográfica en un entorno \longtable en R markdown

Tags: r-markdown

Me podrían ayudar con lo siguiente: quiero colocar una cita bibliográfica[@ejemplo] dentro de un entorno \longtable, pero en su lugar sale @ejemplo.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que has intentado a través de un [repro]. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.